# How to pipe ReadableStream to emscripten layer c code, is that possible?

Tags: ffmpeg, fetch, emscripten

we can get a ReadableStream throw javascript's fetch api, aka [fetch body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body),i want to handle this stream from native c level ,i.e. as a input video source of ffmpeg if the stream was a video. how can i do?